# SQLAlchemy SessionTransaction has query attribute?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm pretty new in Python and SQLAlchemy, so basically I changed from:

```
session = Session()
session.query(SOMETHING_HERE).filter()
```

to

```
session = Session()
nested_session = session.begin_nested()
nested_session.query(SOMETHING_HERE).filter()
```

in order to use SAVEPOINTS. But I'm getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'SessionTransaction' object has no attribute 'query'

I did a deep dive in the documentation, like these:

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.SessionTransaction
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html

But it did not help me.

Questions: Am I able to use begin_nested to run query with filter like that or I need to change the approach? Is this a version issue (sql alchemy for example)?

Comment: You don't need to reassign the result of `session.begin_nested()` to anything, you can just do: `session.begin_nested()` and then proceed with `session.query(SOMETHING_HERE).filter()`.

Comment: Reference for above comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint

Comment: well noted @mechanical_meat, thanks! I'll test it and soon I come back with the feedback. Feel free to add as answer too =]

Comment: I'm glad to know it. I've added an answer. Best wishes with the rest of the project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was originally posted as a comment.

You don't need to reassign the result of `session.begin_nested()` to anything, you can just do: `session.begin_nested()` and then proceed with `session.query(SOMETHING_HERE).filter()`

Reference for this assertion: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint